# Bar graph df.plot() vs ax.bar() structure matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to graph a table as a bar graph.

I get my desired outcome using `df.plot(kind='bar')` structure. But for certain reasons, I now need to graph it using the `ax.bar()` structure.

Please refer to the example screenshot. I would like to graph the x axis as categorical labels like the `df.plot(kind='bar')` structure rather than continuous scale, but need to learn to use `ax.bar()` structure to do the same.

[image]

Comment: don't post code or data as screen shots. it's nearly useless. read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, stacked bar charts are literally the first example on the matplotlib website. Did you you read through that example?

Comment: @PaulH Sorry, I didn't realize. I thought a graphical question would be better understood with a screenshot. I'll learn from this mistake. Thank you.

Comment: I had a look and tried this using their example:
```
labels = list(summary_sm_df.index)

width=3
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(labels, summary_sm_df['ET'], width, color='b')
ax.bar(labels, summary_sm_df['UT'], width, bottom=summary_sm_df["ET"], color='g')
ax.bar(labels, summary_sm_df['CT'], width, bottom=summary_sm_df["ET"]+summary_sm_df['UT'], color='r')```

Comment: Convert `SA` into `str` before setting as index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make the index categorical by setting the type to `'str'`

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'SA': [11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 159, 209, 216],
        'ET': [36, 45, 11, 15, 16, 4, 11, 10],
        'UT': [11, 26, 10, 11, 16, 7, 2, 2],
        'CT': [5, 0.3, 9, 5, 0.2, 0.2, 3, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['SA'] = df['SA'].astype('str')
df.set_index('SA', inplace=True)

width = 3
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

p1 = ax.bar(df.index, df.ET, color='b', label='ET')
p2 = ax.bar(df.index, df.UT, bottom=df.ET, color='g', label='UT')
p3 = ax.bar(df.index, df.CT, bottom=df.ET+df.UT, color='r', label='CT')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]